# ¿poner tres elmentos en una misma linea?

Tags: selectores-css

hola buenas no consigo poner estos tres elementos en modo movil en una misma linea [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

https://marcosocio.com/

Comment: Debes proveer un [mcve] que permita reproducir el problema y por ende dar una eventual solución, checa [ask]